# Can a deaf person be a shaliach tzibbur?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, handicap-disabled-impair, hearing

I recall reading (Mishnah Brurah - don't recall location) that the *shali'ach tzibbur* must wait until everyone answers "amen" before proceeding to thE next bracha. If a deaf person were prompted by someone else using a signal, would this allow him to be a shali'ach tzibbur?

Comment: No. I'm not sure if a deaf person has the same level of obligation, and there's an entire sectioin in SA about requirements for chazzan. will post as answer when I find it.

Comment: Above assumes you have hearing people in minyan. One of all deaf people might not need a chazzan at all. צ"ע

Comment: The ש”ץ needs to have a pleasing voice (I forget the source, although I believe that it is Rambam).

Comment: While I understand that you are quoting a source, there are a few problems with applying it, here. 1) As I understand, the term "pleasing" means there "acceptable" to the congregation." 2) Even with that, said, "pleasing" is objective. I've heard a few chazzanim that sing off key, but the people in my shul love him. 3) You'd be amazed at how some deaf people can sing beautifully. 4) In a minyan where everyone is deaf, the chazan's voice wouldn't matter, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

See Siman 55 in Biur Halacha: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=172&hilite=

Summary: Taz isn't too fond of the idea of having a deaf Shaliach Tzibbur. If he is davening, however, according to Magen Avraham, Gra, Bach and others, it appears we should not remove him from the amud. Rabbi Akiva Eiger concludes that l'chatchila everyone would agree he should not daven at the amud.

EDIT: To speak to Shmuel's point, deaf people have the same level of obligation provided they can communicate verbally. See Shulchan Aruch in same siman.

Comment: Although they have the same level of obligation, are you sure that they can dispense of their obligation as well as hearing people? One is required to pronounce the words loud enough so that he can hear them (משמיע לאזנו) something a deaf person cannot do, making him yotzei only bedieved. Presumably even those authorities that allow him to remain shatz concede this point